# XML comments in NuGet package

Tags: nuget, xml-comments

How do I publish the xml-comments with my assemblies in a NuGet Package so that consumers can see class / method comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add the xml files to the NuGet package alongside your assemblies. Then these comments should be found by Visual Studio and displayed in its intellisense windows.

One example NuGet package that does this is [AvalonEdit](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AvalonEdit/).